# RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData(stream) to verify large files: overcoming assymentric class design

Tags: c#, .net

There is an odd design issue in RSACryptoServiceProvider:

While it is possible to sign very large files using [RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h61axd3h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public byte[] SignData(
    Stream inputStream,
    Object halg
)
```

, there is no way to actually validate the large file without reading the file entirely into a memory buffer.
The only available [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55yk5665%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is:

```
public bool VerifyData(
    byte[] buffer,
    Object halg,
    byte[] signature
)
```

which forces the caller to read the entire file into memory (possible yielding an OutOfMemoryException in the calling code).

I looked into extending the RSACryptoServiceProvider since internally the VerifyData method could be very easily overloaded to support streams. However the class is sealed and internally the method uses a bunch of internal methods that I can't access.

Did anyone run into this issue? Any easy solution to the problem?

BTW - for MS the fix would be a 6 line copy & paste with a single var type change...

Comment: You're not supposed to sign "very large files" with RSACryptoServiceProvider. Signing is for messages in communication. What you want to do is to make a hash.

Comment: VerifyData internally just computes a hash (SignData as well). Couldn't you do that yourself?

Comment: @usr - Unfortunately, VerfiyData first calls a couple of internal methods that I can't access, but I did manage to get something similar to their code to work. I'll add my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does the trick:

```
    public byte[] SignData(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptor, Stream stream, Object halg)
    {
        HashAlgorithm hash = (HashAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName((string) halg); /*Utils.ObjToHashAlgorithm(halg)*/
        byte[] hashVal = hash.ComputeHash(stream);
        return rsaEncryptor.SignHash(hashVal, (string) halg);
    }

    public bool VerifyData(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptor, Stream stream, Object halg, byte[] signature)
    {
        HashAlgorithm hash = (HashAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName((string) halg); /*Utils.ObjToHashAlgorithm(halg)*/
        byte[] hashVal = hash.ComputeHash(stream);
        return rsaEncryptor.VerifyHash(hashVal, (string) halg, signature);
    }
```

and calling it is done by:

```
byte[] signature = SignData(rsa2, stream, "SHA256"); 
//here we write the signature to a file
```

and

```
if (VerifyData(rsaEncryptor, stream, "SHA256", File.ReadAllBytes(signatureFilePath)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Verification completed successfully for file {0}", filePath);
    return true;
}
else
{
    throw new CryptographicException("verification failed for file {0}", filePath);
}
```